# How to fix: Carbon could not be converted to int

Tags: laravel, date, datetime, php-carbon

I have a funtion to get days remaining before a Start Date. I'm using Carbon to handle this in my model like this:

```
    public function getDaysRemainingForFirstPaymentAttribute()
    {
        if (Carbon::createFromTimestamp($this->trip_start_date)->subDays(150) >= (Carbon::now())) {
            return 'Due on'. ' ' .Carbon::parse($this->trip_start_date)->subDays(150)
            ->format('m-d-Y').' | '.Carbon::now()
            ->diffInDays(Carbon::create($this->trip_start_date)
            ->subDays(150), false) . ' ' . 'days';
        } else {
            return 'Due Now';
        }
    }
```

```
//IN MY IF, I have tried:
//if (Carbon::create(...
//if (Carbon::parse(...
```

---

When I Die Dump on `$this->trip_start_date` I get the following date:

```
Illuminate\Support\Carbon @1582347600 {#1006 ▼
  date: 2020-02-22 00:00:00.0 America/New_York (-05:00)
}
```

Then my error is:

> Carbon could not be converted to int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have `$this->trip_start_date` as a Carbon instance and no need to use `Carbon::createFromTimestamp`:

```php
if ($this->trip_start_date->subDays(150) >= Carbon::now()) {
    return 'Due on'. ' ' .$this->trip_start_date->subDays(150)
            ->format('m-d-Y').' | '.Carbon::now()
            ->diffInDays($this->trip_start_date
            ->subDays(150), false) . ' ' . 'days';
}
```

You Can also use [Carbon Comparison](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison) functions:

```php
if ($this->trip_start_date->subDays(150)->gte(Carbon::now())) {
    return sprintf("Due on %s | %s days",
        $this->trip_start_date->subDays(150)->format('m-d-Y'),
        Carbon::now()->diffInDays($this->trip_start_date->subDays(150), false)
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but received same error. On my Return do I need to remove the Carbon::parse and Carbon::create ?

Comment: Thank you! That got it working. Also +1 on the `gte`. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @echo glad it helped.